# Integer bit shifting

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I am trying to build a bit packer for my Huffman encoding.

I have strings in the form of: 01001 that are variable length due to the nature of Huffman encoding. I would like to bit pack these in an integer to save space.

Here is what I am doing in `main`:

```
bitpack.pack(found->second, found->second.size());
```

and inside my bitpack I am doing

```
void BitPacker::pack(std::string stream, int size)
{
    std::cout << "BitPacker received:\t" << stream.c_str() << "\t" << size << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        //if buffer is not full keep shifting
        std::cout << "Buffer index: " << index << std::endl;
        std::bitset<8> binary(buffer);
        std::cout << "Buffer: " << binary << std::endl;

        if(index < 8) {
            if(stream.at(i) == '1') {
                buffer += 1;
                //buffer << 1;
                buffer <<= 1;
                index++;
            }
            else {
                //buffer << 0;
                buffer <<= 1;
                index++;
            }
        }
        //write buffer
        else {
            std::cout << "Writting:\t"<< buffer << std::endl;
            outfile->put(buffer);
            index = 0;
            buffer = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

However it appears I am doing something incorrectly.

What I want to do is to iterate over the stream and if it's a 1, then add the bit then shift it. If it's a 0, I just want to shift. That way I can keep packing in bits to my integer and once it

CODE UPDATED

Comment: First shift, then add for the `'1'` case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem here:

```
 buffer << 1;
```

Does not do anything. It is like writing `x + 1` or `y % 7`; it returns a result but does not modify the value of the variable. I believe you are looking for

```
buffer <<= 1;
```

or

```
buffer = buffer << 1;
```

I'm not familiar with huffman encoding, but this is an obvious problem with the logic of your code.

Also

```
buffer << 0;
```

or even

```
buffer <<= 0;
```

Will have no effect (it is shifting `buffer` by zero bits). What is that line supposed to do?

Comment: i need to build the stream as it exist, so if i have 1001 and the current buffer is 00111001 it will need to now be 10011001, i need to maintain the correct order

Answer (score 1):

please try `buffer=buffer<<1;` to shift it (or how many bits you actually want).

whatever you want to do please note that: `buffer << 0;` does nothing (regarding buffer value)

Answer (score 1):

This line, shifts `buffer` but doesn't store shifter value

```
buffer << 1;
```

you should use something like this

```
buffer <<= 1;
```